# Application works properly in console but terminate in window service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-services, heap-corruption

I made an console application in Visual c++ in VS 2010.  I added the console handler so that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the application may terminate successfully and it worked for me  without error. Later I put the application into a window service and called the same console handler in service console handler in the following the cases  `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` and `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN`.  When I stop the service I get the error

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED:after Normal block(#119) at 0x003C5420.CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.`

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to analyze dump files that are created after this failure.

1. So the first step is [setup collecting dump files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
2. Then build your program in release mode with pdb-files and run it as windows
   service.
3. Finally when you have dump files for this failure you can
   use your debugger to analyze them. I often use for this purpose
   [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx).